# Facing the error "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 24908 (char 24907)"

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load my json file data but I got the following error 
here is my code

```
import json
file = open("js.json" , "r")
json_data = file.read()
file.close()

data = json.loads(json_data)
```

Comment: It looks like you have an invalid json... Note, you can just use `json.load` on the file object directly, instead of `json.loads` on a string.

Comment: when I use json.load on file object it gives me the following error

"json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 24908 (char 24907)"

Comment: Yes, as I explained, you have invalid JSON. I didn't mean that using `json.load` would make this work, just that you were unnecessarily reading from a file.

Comment: So what can I do now